# Is it allowed to put spaces after macro parameter?

Tags: macros, arguments

As shown below, a macro is defined, and can be used without problem without spaces after macro parameter,

```
$$
\def \SpinOrb#1#2{ \chi_#1(\x_#2) }  
\SpinOrb i 2 \SpinOrb j 1
$$
```

[image: No space after macro parameter]

As shown below, the same macro but with one space after macro parameter cannot be used in the same way. Could you suggest why this happens ?

```
$$
\def \SpinOrb#1#2 { \chi_#1(\x_#2) }  
\SpinOrb i 2 \SpinOrb j 1
$$
```

[image: One space after macro parameter]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you do

```
\def\foo#1#2{(#1,#2)}
```

then `#1` and `#2` are *undelimited* arguments. An undelimited argument is either a single token (except `{` or `}`) or a braced group `{...}`. TeX *ignores* spaces when looking at undelimited arguments: from

```
\def\foo#1#2{(#1,#2)}
\foo a b \foo ab \foo {abc}   {def}
```

we get

[image]

On the other hand, when you write

```
\def\foo#1#2 {(#1,#2)}
```

then `#1` is a normal, undelimited argument, but `#2` is now an argument delimited by an *explicit* space token. With this definition you'll find thus

```
\def\foo#1#2 {(#1,#2)}
\foo ab \foo a b
```

[image]

In both cases the space after the control sequence is ignored (as usual) and `a` is grabbed as first (undelimited) argument. Now TeX starts looking at everything which comes before a space. In the first case it finds `b` followed by a space, so `b` is your second argument. But in the second case the first token following `a` *is* a space, so the second argument is empty.

Going specifically to your example

```
\def\SpinOrb#1#2 { \chi_#1(x_#2) }  
\SpinOrb i 2
```

by the TeX rules I just illustrated the `i` is grabbed as first argument, and the second argument is empty, so the code expands effectively to

`\SpinOrb i 2` →  `\chi_i(x_) 2`

and the parenthesis lands as subscript. This is a consequence of omitting braces in the expansion text: even with the correct definition (without space after `#2`) the use of braces in the input would nevertheless lead to unexpected results, since

`\SpinOrb{i}{10}` →  `\chi_i(x_10)`

and you would find the `1` as subscript and a trailing `0`...

Moral: use `\newcommand` instead of `\def`, and don't be too lazy with braces. The way to go is

```
\newcommand*{\SpinOrb}[2]{\chi_{#1}(x_{#2})}  
\SpinOrb{i}{2}
```

and you'll never have problems. Note also  the braces around the arguments in the expansion text; without them you might get unpleasant surprises. Use delimited arguments only if you really want to, and if you really, really know what you are doing.

Answer (score 6):

In TeX, spaces in most places are regular tokens so just adding random spaces will often change the output. In this case, an argument specifier like `#2` which is not followed by a `{` or another argument specifier specifies a delimited argument which captures everything until the first occurrence of the following tokens (in this case a single space). So when parsing `\SpinOrb i 2`, TeX first read the first argument `i` and then is looking at " `2` ". Now it reads everything until the first space as second argument. Since the first character is already a space this makes the second argument empty.