# Parameter text getter

Tags: plain-tex, parameters, def

To this snippet

```
\def\arg#1#2{\#1 = #1 and \#2 = #2\par}
\arg A B C
\end
```

I supposed the output like this one

> #1 = A and #2 =
> B C

But I get (using PDFTeX)

> #1 = A and #2 = B
> C
> .

Why such behavior? I know that space is ignored in some situation (e. g., after a macro) but not, accordingly to my understanding, in this case. What did Mr. Knuth have in mind that none have tell me yet?

Comment: I'm not sure without research why the space after "A" is ignored, but the space after "B" is definitely not ignored.  (It would be ignored if it were `\B` since that is a control sequence.)  So "B" and "C" are definitely not going to be taken together.  That would happen only if you had `\def\arg#1 #2 {...}`.  This definition is context sensitive.  (Not tested.)

Comment: Sorry.. I write down wrongly the expeculated output . I was waiting for a space between B and C. I've rewritten it just now.

Comment: Spaces are always ignored when TeX is looking for undelimited arguments.

Comment: I recognize I've make a simple mistake again... Thank you!

Comment: Well, it's actually not trivial. I'm sure the issue popped out already but I'm unable to find the duplicate I have in mind.

Comment: Anyway TeXbook, page 201, bottom. Or last double dangerous bend paragraph on page 203.

Comment: This is not what I was looking for, but it explains the issue nonetheless (disclaimer: self-publicity): https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/573298/82917

Comment: "...you are allowed to put spaces between the arguments (e.g., ‘\row x n’), because TEX
doesn’t use single spaces as undelimited arguments." From TeX Book, page 201.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On page 201 of the TeXbook you find

> you are allowed to put spaces
> between the arguments (e.g., ‘`\row x n`’), because TeX doesn't
> use single spaces as undelimited arguments.

There’s also another point worthy of attention on page 204

> Argument `#1` will be the token <kbd>Look</kbd>, since `#1` is an undelimited
> parameter (it is followed immediately by `#2` in the definition);
> in this case TeX ignores the blank space after `B`, and strips the
> braces off of `{\Look}`.

The gist of this is that spaces are effectively ignored if they precede an undelimited argument. You *cannot* have a space as an undelimited argument unless you brace it (and the braces will be stripped off).

```
\def\arg#1#2{\#1 = $\langle$#1$\rangle$ and \#2 = $\langle$#2$\rangle$\par}

\arg A{ }B C

\arg A { } B C

\end
```

[image]